# Laravel 5.2: Class log does not exist in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:734

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

I had to clear config and cache, I ran into the following exception :

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class log does not exist in /html/project/bootstrap/cache/compiled.php:1355

I removed `bootstrap/compiled.php` and ran `php artisan clear-compiled`, Then the exception got changed a little bit.

> Class log does not exist in /html/project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:734

Steps i took to solve it :

- Checked env for spaces and syntax errors, Which had a blank space and i removed it, but still my `php artisan` commands are not working.
- Ran composer update  | Still not working
- Some people associate the error with mbstring and php-mysql extensions which i both have.
- Tried composer dumpautoload

What am i missing, How should be done ?

Comment: Try running `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: @aynber have tried that also, Still not working

Comment: Apparently the error message here doesn't really help explain what's going on. You can try `find . -iname '*.php' -exec php -l '{}' \; | grep -v '^No syntax errors'` on the command line to see if it finds any overt errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think somewhere in your code there is a typo like this (note lowercase 'l'):

```
\log::info('test');
```

And that code is executed when `artisan` is executed, so, probably this is somewhere in your console commands, or maybe in some services used by console commands, or maybe some global configuration.

Anyhow, search for '\log::' or 'log::' (in top-level file without namespaces this would result in same error message), and you'll find it.